# React JS: why is useLocation returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an `index.js` which contains

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

The `App` component is structured as follows:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <Route path="/" exact component={NewGamePopup} />
      <Route path="/game" component={Board} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `NewGamePopup` is a popup with a text box for user input and a button with a `Link`

```
<Link to={{pathname: "/game", state: {username: username}}}>
    <button className="ui button">
        Create
    </button>
</Link>
```

The `Board` component which the user get redirected to after clicking the Link contains

```
const { location } = useLocation()
console.log(location);
```

As written in the title, `location` is undefined.

I've read several questions on SO about useLocation returning undefined, but almost everyone was solved wrapping the `App` component with `Router`.  In my case this solution didn't changed anything. How can I make useLocation not returning undefined?

Comment: um,,,, `const location = useLocation();`

Comment: Thank you, sometimes I ask myself where my head is.